# FreeBSD: netatalk3 daemon keeps restarting

Tags: freebsd, daemon, afp, netatalk

I set up a netatalk3 / afpd daemon on my FreeBSD server about half a year ago and used it as networked TimeMachine for my MacBook Pro. Pretty much fire and forget.

Then, beginning of this month, I upgraded from version `3.1.2,1` to `3.1.7,1`.
From what I can reconstruct, that happened as part of the FreeBSD `10.0` --> `10.1` upgrade.

It took me a while to notice that the daemon is not running anymore; actually, the MacBook began to complain about missed backups after a while.

Looking into the issue, it seems the netatalk3 daemon keeps restarting, but even though I've increased the log level in `/usr/local/etc/afp.conf` using `log level = default:debug`, there does not seem to be any hint at what the reason for the restarting is:

```
Jan 24 19:06:24.841243 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:386} (note:Default): Netatalk AFP server starting
Jan 24 19:06:24.843728 cnid_metad[8653] {cnid_metad.c:510} (note:AFPDaemon): CNID Server listening on localhost:4700
Jan 24 19:06:24.844380 netatalk[8651] {afp_avahi.c:80} (info:AFPDaemon): Registering volume 'TimeMachine' with UUID: '<some UUID>' for TimeMachine
Jan 24 19:06:24.844434 netatalk[8651] {afp_avahi.c:94} (info:AFPDaemon): hostname: <hostname>
Jan 24 19:06:24.844451 netatalk[8651] {afp_avahi.c:106} (info:AFPDaemon): Registering server '<hostname>' with Bonjour
Jan 24 19:06:24.845279 netatalk[8651] {afp_avahi.c:302} (info:AFPDaemon): Successfully started avahi loop.
Jan 24 19:06:24.845319 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:456} (note:Default): Registered with Zeroconf
Jan 24 19:06:24.845356 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:218} (info:Default): child[8652]: exited 1
Jan 24 19:06:25.843370 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:254} (note:AFPDaemon): Restarting 'afpd' (restarts: 1)
Jan 24 19:06:25.845151 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:218} (info:Default): child[8654]: exited 1
Jan 24 19:06:26.842367 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:254} (note:AFPDaemon): Restarting 'afpd' (restarts: 2)
Jan 24 19:06:26.844195 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:218} (info:Default): child[8655]: exited 1
Jan 24 19:06:27.846723 netatalk[8651] {netatalk.c:254} (note:AFPDaemon): Restarting 'afpd' (restarts: 3)
  ...
```

Nothing in `/var/log/messages` either. Apart from the `10.1` upgrade, I haven't changed anything on the server; it's just been sitting there doing its thing.

Does anyone have some advice for me how to go about finding the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Isn't this a thing for a freeBSD mailing list/forum? I'd try there :-) Looks like a pkg maintainer has some work to do :-)

Comment: or go straight here: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/

Comment: I was afraid someone was going to say that, but you're right of course. I was just hoping someone has an idea why a server on FreeBSD in general would keep restarting like that - no error message, no hint in any logs ?!?

Comment: Yep, indeed, you've got a case of buggy port/pkg, and lack of beta/production testers :-/

Comment: I couldn't get myself to signing up to yet another mailing list or forum just for a single question, but I got a pointer in IRC `#freebsd`, updating post...

Comment: you should also be able to roll back and then wait for the next update :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just a very wild shot in the dark; netatalk documentation tells this:

> The AFP protocol mostly refers to files and directories by ID and not
>   by name. Netatalk needs a way to store these ID's in a persistent way,
>   to achieve this several different CNID backends are available. The
>   CNID Databases are by default located in the
>   @localstatedir@/netatalk/CNID/(volumename)/.AppleDB/ directory.
>
> cdb
>
> ```
> "Concurrent database", backend is based on Oracle Berkley DB. With this backend several afpd daemons access the CNID database directly.
> ```
>
> Berkeley DB locking is used to synchronize access, if more than one
>   afpd process is active for a volume. The drawback is, that the crash
>   of a single afpd process might corrupt the database.

**BerkeleyDB** has bitten me so many  times in the past (with the other software, I have not used netatalk) that I think it might the problem, yet again. If you are using CDB backend and there are BDB files (`*.bdb` or so) present in that `@localstatedir@.../.AppleDB/` directory, you might try to backup those files somewhere and then run `db_repair` command there. The command name might be `db4.9_repair` or similar, reflecting the current BerkeleyDB version.